# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<SignInBloc> above this BlocConsumer<SignInBloc, SignInState> Widget

Tags: flutter, bloc, provider

I'm creating a login page and I can't figure out why it gives me this error, this is the login page code:

```
class SignInPage extends ConnectivityWidget implements AutoRouteWrapper {
  const SignInPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget wrappedRoute(_) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => SignInBloc(
        authenticationRepository: context.read(),
      ),
      child: this,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget connectedBuild(_) => BlocConsumer<SignInBloc, SignInState>(
    builder: (context, state) => Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 800,
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                image: AssetImage("assets/background.png"),
              ),
            ),
            child: SafeArea(
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(height: 90),
                      // logo
                      /* Whisky and Drink logo */
                      const SizedBox(height: 50),
                      Text(
                        AppLocalizations.of(context)?.title_sign_in ?? '',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 25),
                      //email
                      _emailField(context, enabled: state is! SignInState),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                      //password
                      _passwordField(context, enabled: state is! SignInState),
                      const SizedBox(height: 20),
                      //Sign in Button
                      _signInButton(context, enabled: state is! SignInState),
                      const SizedBox(height: 50),
                      //or continue with
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            const Expanded(
                              child: Divider(
                                thickness: 0.5,
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 10.0),
                              child: Text(
                                AppLocalizations.of(context)?.label_or ?? '',
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const Expanded(
                              child: Divider(
                                thickness: 0.5,
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 50),
                      //google + apple sign in button
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          //google button
                          _googleLoginButton(context,
                              enabled: state is! SignInState),
                          //apple button
                          _appleLoginButton(context,
                              enabled: state is! SignInState),
                        ],
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 100),
                      //Registrati
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)?.label_register ??
                              ''),
                          Text(
                            AppLocalizations.of(context)?.action_register ??
                                '',
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.orange,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    listener: (context, state) {
      _shouldCloseForSignedIn(context, state: state);
      _shouldShowErrorSignInDialog(context, state: state);
    },
  );
```

The error that is returned to me:

```
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<SignInBloc> above this BlocConsumer<SignInBloc, SignInState> Widget
```

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that BlocConsumer<SignInBloc, SignInState> is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>().toString()),
    );
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context, child) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>().toString());
      }
    );
  }
  ```

Could you give me a hand please? I can't find a solution, I've searched everywhere